# Django dropdown filter in querylist

Tags: python, django, filter, dropdown

how can I list the query list with a dropdown filter? with button or dynamicly, thank u!

views;

```
def kibana(request):
    kibana_list = kibanalar.objects.all()
    paginator = Paginator(kibana_list, 1000000000000000)
    page = request.GET.get('page')
    try:
        kmembers = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        kmembers = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        kmembers = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
    return render(request, 'kibanalar.html', {'kmembers': kmembers})
```

models.py;

```
class kibanalar(models.Model):
    datacenter = models.TextField(max_length=100, null=True)
    dashboardtipi = models.TextField(max_length=100, null=True)
    isim = models.TextField(max_length=100, null=True)
    link = models.TextField(max_length=100, null=True)
    kullaniciadi = models.TextField(max_length=100, null=True)
    sifre = models.TextField(max_length=100, null=True)
```

Comment: Does `kibana` not need any parameters except 'request'? You need some info to filter objects.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that I fully understand your question, but it looks like you're trying to display the results of the query `kibana_list = kibanalar.objects.all()` in a dropdown list?

I'm also not sure why you're using pagination if you intend to have 1000000000000000 items on each page... I think their might be a typo or misunderstanding here...

There are several ways you could accomplish a drop-down, depending on your objective.

You could create a `forms.py` and use a `forms.ChoiceField`

Example **forms.py**:

```
from django import forms
from path\to\models.py import kibanalar

class MyForm(forms.Form):
My_Dropdown = forms.Choicefield(choices=createChoicesTuple(), required=False)


def createChoicesTuple():
    value = list(kibanalar.objects.values_list('field_you_want', flat=True))
    display_name = list(kibanalar.objects.values_list('another_field_you_want', flat=True))
    data = tuple(zip(value,display_name))
    return data
```

Another option would be to return the results you want via JsonResponse and insert the response into your HTML via Javascript.